# Using Automated Actions, Update value of a field (on Delivery Order) using value from another field (on Sales Order)

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

Hi and Thanks for your Time

Need Help! In Odoo Online v14, I have created a custom field "X Analytic Account" on Delivery Order model using Odoo Studio. And on Sales Order model, we already have "Analytic Account"(standard) field. Now, what I want is that using Automated Actions in Odoo, whenever a new Delivery Order record is created, odoo should auto-populate  "X Analytic Account" field on Delivery Order using value of "Analytic Account" field which is on parent Sales Order record. Also I want to acheive this automation using  Automated Actions using "Execute Python Code". I have some knowledge on how this can be achieved by making some changes in source code etc. but with Automated Actions I couldn't seem to figure it out.

If possible how this can be done with Automated Actions or with some other option in Odoo Studio? If this is not possible can you please explain whatever limitations there are with Automated Actions.

Thanks a Lot.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit tricky but following automated action worked:

- Model: "Transfer" (stock.picking)
- Trigger: "On Creation & Update"
- Action To Do: "Execute Python Code"
- Following Code:

```py
for record in records:
  analytic_account = record.sale_id.analytic_account_id
  if record.x_studio_analytic_account_id != analytic_account:
    record.write({'x_studio_analytic_account_id': analytic_account.id})
```